# User Feedback through Django Email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an app, in which the main User adds a sub user and sends him an email. I want the sub user to have a button in the email template that would lead him/her to a Feedback form. That feedback form's url must have the user's name in it as it gives a personal touch. But I am not understanding how do I pass the sub user data and save the feedback data against the data. I will create a scenario to make you guys understand better.

**1.** There is a **main user Chris**, Chris **adds a sub user Leon** in his email list. (P.S both are Resident .Evil characters).
**2.** Chris **sends an email** to Leon, Leon will receive the email and if he want he can give a feedback by clicking the feedback button in email.
**3.** If Leon clicks the button he will be redirected to a page where the url could be something like this *(www.feedback/Leon.com)*, there will be form where Leon will add his review and submit.

The problem is how do I save Leon's feed back in the FeedBack model through the email form against his information from the sub user model (PersonData).

#### models.py

```py
class FeedBack(models.Model):
    feedback = models.TextField('Feedback')
    user_feedback = models.ForeignKey(PersonData)


class PersonData(models.Model):

    user_relation = models.ForeignKey(User)
    person_first_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=25)
    person_last_name = models.CharField("last Name", max_length=25)
    person_email = models.EmailField("Email", max_length=512)
```

#### views.py

```py
# class FeedBackCreateView(CreateView):
#     model = FeedBack
#     template_name = "userfiles/FeedBack.html"

#     def form_valid(self, form):
#         obj = form.save(commit=False)
#         obj.user_feedback_id = self.request.persondata_id
#         obj.save()
#         return redirect("Home-Page")



def feedback(request, username):
    person_data = PersonData.objects.get(person_first_name=username)
    item = FeedBack.objects.all().filter(user_feedback=person_first_name)
    form = FeedBackForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)

            profile.employee_name = user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('Home-Page')

    context = {'all_item': all_item}
    return render(request, 'userfiles/AlbumPicsList.html', context)


------------------------------------------------------------------
#This View is from another app called salami. This sends the email
------------------------------------------------------------------

def send_email(request, s_id, pr_id):


    salami_data = SalamiCalculator.objects.get(id=s_id)
    person_data = PersonData.objects.get(id=pr_id)

    context = {'salami_data': salami_data,
               'person_data': person_data}

    subject = "Thank You"
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER  # email from
    to_email = [person_data.person_email]  # email to
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives()
    msg.from_email = email_from
    msg.to = to_email
    msg.subject = subject
    msg.body = salami_data.thankyou_msg

    html_body = render_to_string("salamifiles\email-thanks.html")
    html_template = get_template("salamifiles\email-thanks.html")
    html_content = html_template.render(context)
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    messages.success(request, ("Email Sent !!"))

    return render(request, 'salamifiles\email-thanks.html', context)
```

#### url.py

```
    url(r'^(?i)Feedback/(?P<user_feedback>\w+)/$',
        AlbumPicturesDetail.as_view(), name='Album-Pictures-View'),

==============================================
Salami URL
==============================================
 
   url(r'^Congratsmail/(?P<s_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<pr_id>\d+)/$',
        views.send_email, name='Congrats-EMAIL'),
```

#### forms.py

```py
class FeedBackForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FeedBack
        fields = ("feedback")
```

#### email.html

```html
Have Not Yet modified the email template by adding the button
```

#### Email Sending template

```html
{% for i in items %}

<a href={% url 'Congrats-EMAIL' s_id=i.id pr_id=i.realted_person.id %}>Send Mail</a>

{% endfor %}
```

**=========================================================================**

I expect when Chris send Leon the email, Leon by clicking on the button gets redirected to a page where the URL has his name and the form already is knows he's Leon so that it saves the data against his id/name.

Comment: why can't you add them to the model?

Comment: I am able to save Leon when Chris adds him, but how do I save the Feedback from Leon in the Feedback model. 
Thanks for pointing out the error. I'll correct it ASAP/

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why you cannot do

```
class FeedBack(models.Model):
    feedback = models.TextField('Feedback')
    user_feedback = models.ForeignKey(PersonData, related_name="received_feedbacks")
    giver_feedback = models.ForeignKet(PersonData, related_name="given_feedbacks")
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do with these fields bro?
I'm new to Django can you please guide me a bit.

Comment: The feedback is entered in `feedback` from `giver_feedback` to `user_feedback`

Comment: Please explain as to why are you doing this method?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @HenryM, You can add an extra field for relating to PersonData.

```
class FeedBack(models.Model):
    feedback = models.TextField('Feedback')
    user = models.ForeignKey(PersonData, related_name="received_feedbacks")
    giver = models.ForeignKet(PersonData, related_name="given_feedbacks")
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def feedback(request, username):
    person_data = PersonData.objects.get(person_first_name=username)
    item = FeedBack.objects.all().filter(user_feedback=person_first_name)
    form = FeedBackForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            feedback = form.save(commit=False)
            feedback.user = person_data
            feedback.giver = PersonData.objects.get(user_relation=request.user)
            feedback.save()
            profile.employee_name = user
            profile.save()
            return redirect('Home-Page')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'form_which_renders_feedbackform.html', context)
```

I would recommend using OneToOne relation instead of ForeignKey for `user_relation` field in PersonData. So that you can simply access it via `request.user.persondata`.